# Cleveland's dotplot using Python ggplot

Tags: pandas, python-ggplot, dot-plot

I am very new to ggplot. I am trying to create a dotplot in this fashion.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20621581/229075

I don't have much luck so far. My trial below

```
df=DataFrame({'label':['a', 'b', 'c'], 
              'value':[7, 2, 4]})
ggplot(aes(x="value", y="label"), df) + geom_point()
```

Gives me this error

```
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.pyc in 
           asanyarray(a, dtype, order)
    510 
    511     """
--> 512     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
    513 
    514 def ascontiguousarray(a, dtype=None):

ValueError: could not convert string to float: a
```

I've lookup some a number of docs on R's ggplot. I also have some trouble using construct such as

```
stat="identity"
coord_flip()
geom_bar(weight=?)
```

Are these not yet implemented?

I have Python ggplot version 0.5.0.

Comment: ggplot-python is currnetly not so far as the r ggplot2, so some things don't work. In the above we seem to miss that using a string variable as y needs to be converted to something which matplotlib understands (and not blindingly using it as numbers).

Comment: For the rest: stat="identity" is currently worked on https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/pull/266, coords are totaly not supported right now. Not sure about he `geom_bar(weight)` thingy, could happen that we missed something there. All of this would benefit from some bugreports (and PRs) on github :-)

Comment: Sure. I wasn't sure if I have used it correctly. Will file the issues in Github.